# How to update Project Online enterprise resources standard rate through REST API

Tags: rest, csom, ms-project, sharepoint-jsom

We are currently deploying Project Online and I am looking at ways to sync our enterprise resources rates with our HR system.

I was planning of doing it through the REST API, but to my surprise I cannot find the standard and overtime rates as properties of the enterprise resources object. Did I the correct way of setting those rates or was it ommited by Microsoft ? If so, is there another strategy I could use to sync those rates every night with our HR system ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question and will post info for those like me who ended up on outdated docs through searches :

The doc that is returned in google searches and is being linked at by pretty much everything I have read on Microsoft website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj668539.aspx) is dated. The up to date version can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/project/api/index and contains functions wich had to be added following the deprecation of PSI.